# Stripe: ActionController::UrlGenerationError | No route matches | missing required keys: [:id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am just learning RoR and need I am having trouble with Stripe integration. I have done everything as it says [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/rails) except I have changed "charges" to "charge."

**The error I am receiving is:**
    `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"charge"} missing required keys: [:id]`.

It's not letting me do: `<%= form_tag charge_path do %>`

**This is my controller:**

```
class ChargeController < ApplicationController
def new
end

def create

# Amount in cents
@amount = 0

customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
:email => 'jon@jonkhaykin.com',
:card  => params[:stripeToken]
)

charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
:customer    => customer.id,
:amount      => @amount,
:description => 'Inspire App Charge',
:currency    => 'usd'
)

rescue Stripe::CardError => e
flash[:error] = e.message
redirect_to charge_path
end
end
```

**My routes.rb file has:**
`resources :charge`

### Thank you for your help!

Comment: Once you’ve changed “charges” to “charge” you have RoR naming convention broken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not divert from Rails standards, that will most of the time punish you for it.  You should rename your controller back to `ChargesController` and take a look at "[Singular Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)" on how you can solve your issue.

So the changes that you need to fix your issues are as follows:

1. Rename `app/controllers/charge_controller.rb` to `app/controllers/charges_controller.rb`
2. Rename `class ChargeController` to `class ChargesController`
3. Replace `resources :charge` with `resource :charge`

By replaceing `resources :charge` with `resource :charge` you will be creating a singular charge resource with the path `/charge`.

With your current setup i.e. `resources :charge` you will see the following (which is not what you want):

```
charge_index   GET    /charge(.:format)              charge#index
               POST   /charge(.:format)              charge#create
new_charge     GET    /charge/new(.:format)          charge#new
edit_charge    GET    /charge/:id/edit(.:format)     charge#edit
charge         GET    /charge/:id(.:format)          charge#show
               PUT    /charge/:id(.:format)          charge#update
               DELETE /charge/:id(.:format)          charge#destroy
```

As you can see above the `charge_path` resolves to `charge#show` but if you look at the path it also requires an `:id` parameter which you are not supplying in your `form_tag :charge_path` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your controller name to `ChargesController`, change the path helper to `charges_path` and the routes to `resources :charges`.

Also, the form should be `POST`ing.