# Rails form for multiple objects, ActionController UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, actioncontroller

**Problem with routing in a rails form_tag for collection of items**
ActionController::UrlGenerationError

**Goal:**
I have an array of **movies** that I show on movies#index page. I have created a **movie_vote** relationship between movies and users, and want to show a vote form for each movie on the movies#index page so that **users** can vote for the movie. If the user has voted for the movie before, the vote relationship between the user and movie is destroyed.

**Controllers:**
Movies,
MovieVotes,
Users

I've looked at 
[ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Book#new](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472363/actioncontrollerurlgenerationerror-in-booknew)

and http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html,

and [Stripe: ActionController::UrlGenerationError | No route matches | missing required keys: [:id]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450541/stripe-actioncontrollerurlgenerationerror-no-route-matches-missing-requir) but to no avail

**Setup:**

config/routes.rb

```
resources :movies  
resources :users
resources :movie_votes
```

controllers/movie_votes_controller.rb

```
def create
  movie = Movie.find(params[:voted_movie_id])
  current_user.vote!(@movie)
  respond_to do |format|
     format.html {redirect_to movies_path}
     format.js
  end
end

def destroy
    movie = Movie.find(params[:voted_movie_id])
    current_user.unvote!(@movie)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to movies_path }
      format.js
    end
end
```

app/models/movie_votes.rb

```
class MovieVotes < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :voter_id, class_name: "Users"
  belongs_to :voted_movie_id, class_name: "Movies"
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movies
  has_many :movie_votes, foreign_key: "voter_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :voted_movies, through: :movie_votes
end
```

app/models/movies.rb

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :movie_votes, foreign_key: "voted_movie_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :voters, through: :movies_votes
end
```

app/views/movies/index.html.erb

```
<% @movies.each do |m| %>
    <% voter_result = m.voters.where('id' => current_user.id) %>
    <% if (voter_result != [] && voter_result != nil) %>
        <%=form_tag(controller: "movie_votes", action: "destroy", method: "delete") do |f| %>
            <% f.hidden_field :voted_movie_id, :value => m.id %>
            <% f.hidden_field :voter_id, :value => 4 %>
            <%= f.submit %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But when running rails s, I get this problem:

**Error:**

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Movies#index
No route matches {:action=> "destroy", :controller=>"movie_votes", :method=>"DELETE"}
```

So I've tried switching the method and action in the form_tag in movies/index.html.erb, making them the same, but I still can't figure it out.

When I 'rake routes' I get:

```
    movie_votes GET    /movie_votes(.:format)          movie_votes#index
                POST   /movie_votes(.:format)          movie_votes#create
 new_movie_vote GET    /movie_votes/new(.:format)      movie_votes#new
edit_movie_vote GET    /movie_votes/:id/edit(.:format) movie_votes#edit
     movie_vote GET    /movie_votes/:id(.:format)      movie_votes#show
                PATCH  /movie_votes/:id(.:format)      movie_votes#update
                PUT    /movie_votes/:id(.:format)      movie_votes#update
                DELETE /movie_votes/:id(.:format)      movie_votes#destroy
```

Does anyone have any pointers to how to formulate the form_tag in movies#index code?

Comment: Try Changing `controller: "movie_vote"` to `controller: "movie_votes"` in your `form_tag`.

Comment: Hi @Pavan, I have, but I get the same result. Thanks though for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

as I can see you are missing model for this app , it is all about how many time can one user vote for some movie and this kind of stuff you need to define in model have a look this link

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

So if you ask me this is what you need :)

Comment: Hi I do have it. I've included in the info above for reference though. Thanks!